# how to solve error non-numeric argument to binary operation

Tags: r, return

I want to calculate the stock return but I got error in

```r
return=function(x)
  {
    n=length(x)
    x=matrix(x,nrow=n,ncol=1)
    return_data=matrix(nrow=n-1,ncol=1)
    for(i in 1:n-1)
    {
      return_data[i]=log(x[i+1,]/x[i,])
    }
    return_data
  }

R_JSMR=return(JSMR)
```

> Error in x[i + 1, ]/x[i, ] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

how do I solve this? please help me, thank you very much :)

Comment: What is the structure of `JSMR`?

Comment: Don't name your function `return`. `return` is a defined function used in building functions. Terrible things can happen... better name it `my_return` or something like that.

Comment: You are missing parenthesis in `for(i in 1:n-1)`, it should be `1:(n-1)`. Also, it's not wrong but you are not using the `x` matrix structure, only the return value. It's pointless to coerce `x` to matrix. Remove that instruction and in the loop do `log(x[i+1]/x[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is to have the `for` loop in `1:n-1` instead of `1:(n-1)`. Here is the function corrected and a vectorized version of it.

```
log_returns <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  return_data <- matrix(nrow = n - 1, ncol = 1)
  for(i in 1:(n-1)) {
    return_data[i] <- log(x[i+1]/x[i])
  }
  return_data
}
log_returns2 <- function(x) {
  return_data <- log(x[-1]/x[-length(x)])
  matrix(return_data, ncol = 1)
}

JSMR <- 1:10
R_JSMR <- log_returns(JSMR)
R_JSMR2 <- log_returns2(JSMR)
identical(R_JSMR,R_JSMR2)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you don't need to return a matrix, here are two one-liners.

```
log_returns3 <- function(x) log(x[-1]/x[-length(x)])
log_returns4 <- function(x) diff(log(x))
```